# keep a variable type when I get value from input onchange with React-hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  
  return (
    <input type="number" value={num} onChange={(e)=>setNum(parseInt(e.target.value))} />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

I want to keep `num`'s type as `Number`, not `String`.

but, `onChange=(e=>setNum(e.target.value))` makes `num`'s type `String`

I tried to change like this `onChange={e=>setNum(parseInt(e.target.value))}`.

but, when I inputted `white-space`, It occurs error.

> Warning: Received NaN for the `value` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.

What is the best way to keep `num`'s type?

Comment: you have a synthax error. `onChange={...}`. You have normal () instead of {}

Comment: @VlatkoVlahek ignore it.

Comment: Sorry, guys. I have just edited my question.

Comment: guys, I am re-writing with code snippets.

Comment: Input validation is needed if you want to avoid the NaN. You either need to replace the NaN with a value, or abort the change all together if it results in a NaN. both solutions will be inconvenient to the user, as if the value becomes invalid while they're typing out a valid value, it will replace their input with whatever you tell it to, or do nothing. You might be better off making this *not* a controlled input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue stems from the fact that **parseInt** can break.

In case you cannot successfully parseInt your "string" input value, you will get an error. You can add a fallback to current value or reset to 0, or avoid calling setNum in case your parseInt fails.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  return (
    <input
      type="number"
      onChange={e => setNum(parseInt(e.target.value) || num)}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: it blocks to input `white-space`, I want to keep type number when I type number.

Comment: Maybe, you gave me a big hint, `setNum(parseInt(e.target.value) || '')`

Comment: Glad that it led you in the right direction. However, setNum with `' '` should not work tbh, as you are falling back to a string for a numeric value.

Comment: This code will prevent the user setting `num` to zero if it is currently non-zero.  Consider checking parseInt's return value for NaN rather than falsiness, as a return value of 0 is falsy but may be a legit user input.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I just bypassed it by having the value of the input be equal to either the state or an empty string. that way it won't affect the state of the value and it will just be an empty string.

```
<input
  type="number"
  onChange={e => setNum(parseInt(e.target.value))}
  value = {num || ""}
/>
```

with this, I also added validation to make sure num does not stay as a NAN for long.

Comment: Nice idea to keep it also away from being 0.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by checking the NaN value.

```
<input
  type="number"
  onChange={e => {
      Object.is(NaN, parseInt(e.target.value))
          ?setNum(e.target.value)
          :setNum(parseInt(e.target.value))
      }
  }
  value = {num}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `parseInt()` you can also use `Number()` where the blank whitespace will automatically be converted to `0`.

In case you the input field to be empty you use the `defaultValue` instead of `value`
like this

```
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  //changes made below
  return (
    <input type="number" defaultValue={num} onChange={(e)=>setNum(Number(e.target.value))} />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

However in your case the default value is `0` because that's the initial value of `num`

You can change it to this `const [num, setNum] = useState('');`

Note : It will only work for all numbers including decimals