# Cannot provide defaultValue as an expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the below React component, why will `defaultValue={time}` work, but `defaultValue={time / 2}` will not (will display empty input)?

Please note that I want to keep the `useEffect` hook and also not change `defaultValue` to `value`.

Please try it on the following sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-gn5yw?file=/src/index.tsx

```
const Input = () => {

    const [time, setTime] = React.useState()

    React.useEffect(() => setTime(1000), [])

    return <input defaultValue={time / 2} type="number" />
}
```

Comment: If you check the console, there's an error: *"Received NaN for the `defaultValue` attribute*". It will not throw an error for the initial value is `undefined`. But for `undefined / 2`, which is NaN. [keep a variable type when I get value from input onchange with React-hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56381007)

Comment: You can set an initial value like: `React.useState(0)`

Answer (score 1):

The defaultValue is the passive original value entered that's why it can't be changed dynamically inside the attribute, whereas the value attribute is perceived as a dynamic value that can be changed.
If you want to set defaultValue dynamically you'd have to do it inside the useEffect function before your component is rendered.

```js
const Input = () => {

    const [time, setTime] = React.useState()

    React.useEffect(() => setTime(1000 /2), [])

    return <input defaultValue={time} type="number" />
}
```